# How to prove the ceiling relations stated in CLRS Introduction to Algorithms book?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

In the book ["Introduction to Algorithms", by CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844), page 54, the following relations are stated (enumeration is mine):

---

For any real number $x\geq 0$ and integers $a,b>0$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
(1)\qquad\left\lceil\dfrac{\lceil x/a\rceil}{b}\right\rceil&=\left\lceil\dfrac{x}{ab}\right\rceil\\
(2)\qquad\qquad\left\lceil\dfrac{a}{b}\right\rceil&\leq\dfrac{a+(b-1)}{b}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

I'd like to come up with a proof for these relations, but I'm getting nowhere.

For (1), I understand that I need to somehow prove that, for $m=\lceil x/a\rceil$ and $n=\lceil x/ab\rceil$, it is the case that

$$
\lceil n/b\rceil-1<n/b\leq\lceil n/b\rceil\text{ if and only if }m-1<x/a\leq m
$$

I tried manipulating different inequalities but the obstacle I'm facing is that I can't find any useful way to relate $n$ with $m$. Ideally, I imagine that (somehow) I should be able to remove the ceiling signs around $\lceil x/a\rceil$, manipulate the resulting expression to come up with $x/ab$, and then return the ceiling signs to get $\lceil x/ab\rceil$. I don't see how this could be possible, though.

For (2), I started in a similar fasion. Letting $n=\lceil a/b\rceil$, I know from the definition of the ceiling function that $n-1<a/b\leq n$. So, what I want to prove is that
$$
n\leq\dfrac{a+b-1}{b}
$$
I thought this could be proven in a straighforward fashion using algebra, but the obstacle I'm facing is that the relation has a $\leq$ sign, instead of a $<$ sign (which I can easily obtain from the definition of the ceiling function).

Any tips on how I could get started with these proofs will be very much appreciated.

Comment: FYI, for your first relation, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cleft%5Clceil%5Cfrac%7B%5Clceil%20x%2Fa%5Crceil%7D%7Bb%7D%5Cright%5Crceil%3D%5Cleft%5Clceil%5Cdfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bab%7D%5Cright%5Crceil%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Areal%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1), there's [Nested Division in the Ceiling Function](/q/233670), [Proof regarding the ceiling function.](/q/2614520), etc. For your second relation, using an ...

Comment: (cont.) [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cleft%5Clceil%5Cdfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%5Cright%5Crceil%5Cleq%5Cdfrac%7Ba%2B(b-1)%7D%7Bb%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Areal%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1), there's [How to Show that $1+\left(\left\lceil\dfrac{x}{n}\right\rceil -1\right)n\leq x$?](/q/1736247) (where the inequality becomes $n\left\lceil\frac{x}{n}\right\rceil+1-n\le x$, then $\left\lceil\frac{x}{n}\right\rceil\le\frac{x+(n-1)}{n}$), [floor ceiling proof](/q/996924), etc. Also, in the future, please ask about each separate problem in different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (2), consider that

$$ \frac{a + b}{b} = \frac{a}{b} + 1 > \bigg\lceil \frac{a}{b} \bigg\rceil $$

We can "sharpen" this inequality by choosing the largest number less than $a/b + 1$ that could possibly be the value of the ceiling expression. That means that it will have to be an integer for *some* value of $a/b$.

Since $a/b$ is a fraction with denominator $b$, the difference between it and an integer will have the same denominator. Thus, there will be some $k\in \Bbb Z$ such that

$$ \bigg\lceil \frac{a}{b} \bigg\rceil \leq \frac{a}{b} + \frac{k}{b} $$

We already know $k/b < 1$ and so $k < b$. So we ask: can be $k = b-1$? Well, if $a \equiv 1 \text{ mod } b$, then

$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b-1}{b} = \frac{(kb+1) + (b - 1)}{b} = k+1 \in \Bbb Z $$

Thus,

$$ \bigg\lceil \frac{a}{b} \bigg\rceil \leq \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b-1}{b} = \frac{a+b-1}{b}$$

where equality holds iff $a \equiv 1 \text{ mod } b$.

---

For (1):

If $\frac{x}{ab} \in \Bbb Z$, then $x/a \in \Bbb Z$ as well and so $\lceil x/a \rceil = x/a$ and the result is trivial. Similarly, if $b=1$, the result is trivial. From here on out, assume neither is the case.

We have

$$ \bigg\lceil \frac{x}{a} \bigg\rceil < \frac{x}{a} + 1 $$

and so

$$ \frac{\lceil x/a \rceil}{b} < \frac{x}{ab} + \frac{1}{b} $$

There are two cases to consider: $\lceil x/a \rceil / b \in \Bbb Z$ or it's not.

In the former case, we have that

$$ \frac{\lceil x/a \rceil}{b} > \frac{x}{ab} > \frac{\lceil x/a \rceil}{b} - \frac{1}{b} > \frac{\lceil x/a \rceil}{b} - 1 $$

In the latter case, an argument similar to the one for (2) shows that

$$ \bigg\lfloor \frac{\lceil x/a \rceil}{b} \bigg\rfloor  \leq \frac{\lceil x/a \rceil}{b} - \frac{1}{b} < \frac{x}{ab} < \frac{\lceil x/a \rceil}{b} <\bigg\lfloor \frac{\lceil x/a \rceil}{b} \bigg\rfloor + 1 $$

In either case, both $\frac{\lceil x/a \rceil}{b}$ and $\frac{x}{ab}$ are in the same interval $(k,k+1]$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$, i.e.

$$ \bigg\lceil \frac{x}{ab} \bigg\rceil = \bigg\lceil \frac{\lceil x/a \rceil}{b} \bigg\rceil $$

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a proof for (1), but it requires us to first prove the following lemma, which I found in ["Concrete Mathematics", by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025), page 71, alongside it's proof (which I'm also posting below). The lemma goes like this:

---

**Lemma 1**. *Let $f$ be any continuous, monotonically increasing function with the special property that: if $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then, we have $\lfloor f(x)\rfloor=\lfloor f(\lfloor x\rfloor)\rfloor$ and $\lceil f(x)\rceil=\lceil f(\lceil x\rceil)\rceil$, whenever $f(x)$, $f(\lfloor x\rfloor)$ and $f(\lceil x\rceil)$ are defined.*

**Proof**. Only the proof for the ceiling function will be shown, since the proof for the floor function is similar. Let $x$ be any real number in the domain of $f$. By the definition of the ceiling function, we have that $x\leq\lceil x\rceil$.

First, let $x=\lceil x\rceil$. In this case, we have $f(x)=f(\lceil x\rceil)$ and, consecuently, $\lceil f(x)\rceil=\lceil f(\lceil x \rceil)\rceil$. This ends the proof for this case.

Now, let $x<\lceil x\rceil$. This implies that $f(x)<f(\lceil x\rceil)$, since $f$ is monotonically increasing. Consecuently, we have $\lceil f(x)\rceil\leq\lceil f(\lceil x\rceil)\rceil$, since the ceiling function is non-decreasing. Next, we're going to prove that $\lceil f(x)\rceil=\lceil f(\lceil x\rceil)\rceil$ by developing a contradiction. Assume that $\lceil f(x)\rceil<\lceil f(\lceil x\rceil)\rceil$. We've arrived to the following relation:
$$
f(x)\leq\lceil f(x)\rceil<\lceil f(\lceil x\rceil)\rceil.
$$
Since $f$ is continuous, there exists a value $x'$ in the domain of $f$ for which the following relation is true:
$$
x\leq x'<\lceil x\rceil\text{ and }f(x')=\lceil f(x)\rceil,
$$
and by the special property of $f$, we have that $x'\in\mathbb{Z}$. However, there can be no integer that is strictly between $x$ and $\lceil x\rceil$ (since $\lceil x\rceil$ is the minimum integer greater than $x$). Thus, we've reached a contradiction. Therefore, we conclude that $\lceil f(x)\rceil=\lceil f(\lceil x\rceil)\rceil$. **Q.E.D.**

---

We can now use Lemma 1 to prove relation (1). Observe that we can define a function $g$ as
$$
g(x)=\dfrac{x}{b}.
$$
This function is continuous and monotonically increasing (since $x/b$ is a linear function), and also has the special property that $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ if $g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}$ (since the only way for $x/b$ to be an integer is if $x$ is a multiple of $b$). Thus, we can apply Lemma 1 to $g(x/a)$ to get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lceil g(x/a)\rceil &= \lceil g(\lceil x/a\rceil)\rceil\\
\therefore\left\lceil\dfrac{x}{ab}\right\rceil &= \left\lceil\dfrac{\lceil x/a\rceil}{b}\right\rceil,
\end{aligned}
$$
thus proving relation (1).